# How do i sample 6000 elements out of my 4-d array in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random, reshape

So I'm working with an array named `train_images` of shape **(25036, 12, 15, 15)**  , I need to select 6000 random samples from this array,

I've tried using `np.random.choice()`
[image: screenshot of error message]

It returned the error above, seems like it needs to be 1 dimensional, and I definitely do not want to reshape the array,

Please is there any way to get around this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select `6000` random samples from your 4D array without reshaping, you can use `np.random.choice()` to generate random indices and then use these indices to select the samples from the array.

Following is the sample code:

```
num_samples = 6000
indices = np.random.choice(train_images.shape[0], num_samples, replace=False)
selected_samples = train_images[indices]
```

Here, we first `6000` random indices without replacement, then use these indices to select the corresponding samples from the `train_images` array. The resulting `selected_samples` array will have a shape of `(6000, 12, 15, 15)`.